# Removing and renaming files with C error

Tags: c, file, text

So i'm trying updating data from original file to a new temporary file, then i remove the original file and rename the temp file with the name of the original one like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
 FILE * fptr = NULL;
 FILE * temp;

    fptr = fopen("Original.txt", "rw+");
    temp = fopen("temp.txt", "w");

    if(fptr==NULL)//Check if file was opened successfully
    {
        printf("File could not be opened");
    }


    //cicle of me adding data to temp file

    fclose(fptr);
    fclose(temp);

    remove("Original.txt");
    rename("temp.txt","Original.txt");

    return 0;
    }
```

it works the first time, but when i execute again the Original.txt ends up blank. What can be causing that?

I've tried changing temp = fopen("temp.txt", "w"); to temp = fopen("temp.txt", "ab+"); but the info of Original.txt ends up with no spaces or new lines between (all together). And same with "wb"

"rb" the Original.txt file disappears.

if necessary ill add the entire code, althought i dont think its revelant

Comment: Why do you open and close the files ?

Comment: @phoxis from what ive learned people close the files and then they remove or rename

Comment: `rw+` has undefined behaviour!

Comment: Why do you check that `fptr` is NULL, but do not check the status of `temp`?  Opening for writing can also fail.  Also, error messages should explain why the call failed, and be written to stderr.  `if( (fp = fopen(path, mode)) == NULL ) { perror(path); ...}`

Answer (score 2):

The moment you do an `fopen (path, "w")` it truncates the file pointed by the `path`. Then you close the file. Therefore essentially, your "temp.txt" is an empty file after the line `fclose (temp)`. Get rid of the "w+" and "w" as they will truncate the file (make it zero length).

See `man fopen`

> w      Truncate file to zero length or create text file for writing. 
>   The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file.
>
> w+     Open for reading and writing.  The file is created if it does not exist, otherwise it is truncated.  The stream is positioned
>   at the beginning of the file.

You do not need to open and or close the file at all. If you see the `remove` and `rename` uses absolutely nothing from the previous part of the code. Also check `man rename` and `man remove`. If you want to know if the files are present of not. Check the return values of these functions. In case of error, you can always inspect the `errno` to understand what exactly went wrong. (See manpage for details).

Comment: but to write in the temp.txt i have to open it, right?

Comment: If you want to write something, then you have to, but there is no need to open the files, as the `rename` and `remove` functions accept the file path, and for the renaming and removing actions, use those paths to open and close the files for the actions internally.

If you want to write to the file, which is independent to removal and/or renaming, then just do it normally. If you want to preserve the previous contents, use the append mode "a" or "a+" for append and read mode.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to do exactly, but depending on your question, you need only "r" mode for reading.

### i.e,  `fptr = fopen("Original.txt", "r");`

Additionally, couple of suggestions, but not answer to your question:

1. You are checking `fptr == NULL`, but proceeding to write data anyway? what if `fptr == NULL` is true and you try to read from a NULL pointer? Besides putting an error message, put a `return -1` or something so that the program does not continue further for that case.
2. You should check `temp == NULL` as well, to detect whether file is opened for writing also. What if `temp == NULL` is true and you try to write to a NULL pointer?